# Create_login_url error after migrating to HRD (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm receiving an error when trying to hit my newly migrated Google App Engine HRD app.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 710, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~***-hrd/1.361484826407666031/***.py", line 37, in get
    return self.redirect(users.create_login_url('self.request.uri'))
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 256, in create_login_url
    raise NotAllowedError
NotAllowedError
```

I'm encountering this problem immediately after duplicating and deploying my app.  I still also receive it after migrating my datastore (which completes without any issues) from master-slave to HRD.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I fixed this by adding the newly created app id to my google apps domain control panel.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth

I also changed from `using users.create_login_url` to using login: required in the `app.yaml`.

Comment: Are you trying to reach the old app id, or the new one?

Comment: I'm trying to read the new one.   The old app id still works actually.

Comment: consider answering your own question